# windows environment $HADOOP_HOME context and file system type

Tags: windows, hadoop

**Problem**

My version of windows does not have a Settings for Advanced Environment to edit system variables. Alternately, I must write my own $HADOOP_HOME variable and save it.

**Missing the Window System About Advanced System Opption**

In the version of Window, I do not have:

**System** > **About window**, click the **Advanced system** settings link below the Device specifications section.
In the **System Properties** window, click the **Advanced** tab.
Click the **Environment Variables** button near the bottom-right of the Advanced tab.

I am setting this up for Java project to enable the build path to have my hadoop-core/common/mapreduce-client jar files accessible to my Eclipse IDE in my Java code and the Java Build Path which has the following classpath entries for hadoop Jar files.

```
Classpath
hadoop-common-2.0.0-alpha.jar - C:Users/matth/Documents/MasterENG/HadopJars/
hadoop-core-2.0.0.jar - C:Users/matth/Documents/MasterENG/HadopJars/
hadoop-mapreduce-client.jar - C:Users/matth/Documents/MasterENG/HadopJars/
```

**What is File Types**

First question is what is the specific file type for a window system variable?
I have saved this custom command / text editor Windows Variables but now need to convert it to a system variable?

**What Directory Location**

Second question, what directory system location for windows system variables and which directory location is it appropriate to add this $HADOOP_HOME for my Eclipse IDE Java Build Path to resolve the jar files on compile, and remove the failed accessibility now because there is no HADOOP_HOME system variable.

**Command Variable File**

Third question. For my command variable file, I have started with a notepad to save a text file with the windows "setx" command, and added the necessary "Path" and "Hadoop_Home" with its path information. This is stated below:

```
setx PATH %PATH%; %HADOOP_HOME%
setx $HADOOP_HOME/Users/matth/Documents/MasterENG/HadoopJars
```

Comment: Windows system variables are not a file type. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: My Windows does not have: System > About window, click the Advanced system settings link below the Device specifications section. In the System Properties window, click the Advanced tab. Click the Environment Variables button near the bottom-right of the Advanced tab.

Comment: That's nice. I guess you won't be setting any Windows system environment variables then. You could *try* telling us what version of Windows you actually have. Instead of telling us in detail about things that you don't have.

Comment: Windows version 10.0.22621; sorry forgot that important info

Comment: I was just not able to find this Windows system environment variables on this computer, I work mostly on Mac

Comment: If you type "Environment variable" or maybe "System variable" in the start menu, it sends you correctly to the control panel... Otherwise, use WSL2 or a VM to run Hadoop things not directly in Windows host. Then you will have a bashrc file to edit... Besides this, hadoop 2.0.0 is very old (released 2012). Why are you trying to use this version? And your home directory needs to have a bin folder, not just jar files

Comment: Also, no one really writes mapreduce code anymore, but maybe you can try executing example code from my repo? https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox